# Directive link function not called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a portion of view that refreshes itself, say the div hides when an API call is in progress and shows up when the response is obtained.

This portion of view (div) has a angular directive.

View

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl>
    <input type="button" ng-click="callAPI()">
    <div ng-show="isAPICallComplete">
        <p data-my-directive="something" ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive

```
angular.module('myModule')
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.callAPI = function () {
         $http.get('someURL').then(function (response) {
             $scope.isAPICallComplete = true;
             $scope.names= response.names;
         });
     }
})
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('reached directive');
        }
    }
});
```

With the above code, on page load the API call is already complete and hence the div shows up which then invokes the angular directive and I could see the log in console. But when on other conditions the API is called, the div hides itself and shows up again. In this case, the angular directive is not invoked (I don't see the console log message).

Comment: *"But when on other conditions the API is called, the div hides itself and shows up again"* Post code for this.

Comment: shouldn't that be <p my-directive> since you defined the directive as myDirective?

Comment: @Shivi its an html5 representation of placing angular syntax, you can write data-ng- anything you want in angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can Do:**

Just change the ng-show to ng-if it will work,
As the DOM will be created again on using ng-if

Comment: Thank you. Changing to ng-if instead of ng-show helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought it is worth mentioning

`ng-if` removes or adds the element to the DOM whereas `ng-show` only hides or shows the element using css properties.